# Overloading Operator + with two arrays c++

Tags: arrays, c++11, operator-overloading, this

```
DynamicArray DynamicArray::operator+(const DynamicArray& rhs) const
{
    int count = 0;
    int tempCapcacity = mCapacity;
    int newCapacity = mCapacity + rhs.mCapacity;

    string *temp = allocateAndCopyToNewArray(mWords, mNumWords, newCapacity);

    for (int i = tempCapcacity; i < newCapacity; i++)
    {
       temp[i] = rhs.mWords[count];
       count++;
    }

    return *this;
 }
```

Trying to have a overloaded operator combine two arrays of strings. The function has to be const so I am not able to change member data. How can I return this temp array?

Comment: You can't as the code stands right now. You need to create a new `DynamicArray` where you store the result and return that.

Comment: We don't know `DynamicArray` internals...

Answer (score 0):

You can instead make it a non-member function. So it doesn't have to be const. I'm not sure how your DynamicArray implementation works so I will just use std::vector function stubs to represent what I'm thinking

```
    template<typename T>
    DynamicArray<T> operator + (const DynamicArray<T?& lhs, const DynamicArray<T>& rhs)
    {
        const uint prev_size = lhs.size();
        DynamicArray result = lhs;
        result.resize(result.size() + rhs.size()); // Let whatever internal resizing policy take over
        memcpy(&result.data()[prev_size], rhs.data(), rhs.size() * sizeof(T));
        return result;
    }
```

Essentially what I do here is I make a copy of lhs, I then add the needed elements to make the list able to be copied over with sufficient space, then I copy the rhs data at the start of the other's end. Adding them